# JS variable "disappear" with no reason and gets empty

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to get lat and long info from Google Geocoder, but although the information is properly extracted on the call that is being done, for some reason the js variable gets empty imediately after getting to my second alert on this piece of code (the one outside "if" condition):

```js
var map, marker, latLong;
var geocoderlat = new google.maps.Geocoder();   
var addresslat = '<?php echo str_replace(" ","+",$address);?>';
function initMap() {
 
 geocoderlat.geocode( { 'address': addresslat}, function(results, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  latLong = results[0].geometry.location;
  alert("Inside IF: "+latLong);
   } else {
  latLong = '<?php echo $latitude.",".$longitude;?>';
   }
 })
 
 alert("Outside: "+latLong);

    var isDraggable = !('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement);
 var mapOptions = { 
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(latLong),
   zoom: 12,
      (...)
```

Obviously there's a lot of code besides this part, but the rest of the code doesn't matter in this case because this variable is never again used anywhere in my code (I even searched with Agent Ransack all over the files so be sure that this variable was not being used anywhere else).

EDIT:

Ok, this is really, really weird...

```js
function getGeoLatLong(addresslat) {
  geocoderlat.geocode( { 'address': addresslat}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      return results[0].geometry.location;
    } else {
      return '<?php echo $latitude.",".$longitude;?>';
    }
  })
}

alert("Outside function: "+getGeoLatLong(addresslat));
```

This still returns "undefined" in the alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`geocoderlat.geocode` is taking more time to execute while the code execution has already reached your second alert. you need to use `setTimeout` to check the results or try this.

```
function initMap() {    
    geocoderlat.geocode( { 'address': addresslat}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        latLong = results[0].geometry.location;
        alert("Inside IF: "+latLong);
        alert("Outside: "+latLong);

    var isDraggable = !('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement);
    var mapOptions = { 
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(latLong),
      zoom: 12,
      (...)
      } else {
        latLong = '<?php echo $latitude.",".$longitude;?>';
      }
    })
```

Also, if you want to use `latLong = '<?php echo $latitude.",".$longitude;?>';` as the default `latLong` you need to declare it at the top. then it will be anyways overridden when geocode finishes loading

EDIT
Try this.

```
function getGeoLatLong(addresslat) {
 geocoderlat.geocode( { 'address': addresslat}, checkresults)
}
function checkresults(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      alert("Outside function: " + results[0].geometry.location);
    //declare the big chunk of code as a function and make a call to it.
    } else {
      alert("Outside function: <?php echo $latitude.','.$longitude;?>");
     //declare the big chunk of code as a function and make a call to it.
    }
  }

   getGeoLatLong(addresslat);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I actually though in that, but since the code is a BIG chunk bellow that, it would mean that I would have to replicate my code on the "else" as well. What if I put that geocoder inside a function and simply call that function?

Comment: That would be great. using functions is always good. make sure you pass all the internally declared variables to your function.

Comment: I am not doing something right here, because even with a function, it's still returning "undefined" as result! :S

Comment: Edited my answer @Pedro. Geocode service makes an asynchronous call to google api (ajax call). this may take a while, hence the alert wont happen instantaneously. You need to write all your next code in the callback function

Comment: It's working! Finally... I actually had already though in what you suggested, but I didn't wanted to do it that way because I didn't wanted to unecessarily duplicate my code, so what I ended up doing was placing the "})" that closes "geocoderlat.geocode" and the function inside it, in the very end of the big chunk of code. And guess what, no errors and working perfectly! :) Thank you for helping me thinking clearer. :D

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Rohit Agre would you mind upvoting my question so that I can increase my reputation? I lost possibility to place new questions. :( Thanks a lot in advance.